# Play video in html5 from presigned amazon url

Tags: html, url, video

Is it possible to play video in html5 from presigned amazon url?

For example, here I have a presigned amazon url:

> https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zed-content/Activity%20Contents/test%20act%20Content/testVid47.MOV?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ7V4MJWO3GNAM6WA%2F20180829%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20180829T082051Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-Signature=7ec66a41cc4c536ccc4abd42e5fea3621438563b114f72dd26f71c14eb4c4edd&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host

When I click it a video starts to download. But when I try to do this:

```
    <video class="videoElement" data-aura-rendered-by="116:582;a">
      <source src="https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/zed-   content/Activity%20Contents/test%20act%20Content/testVid47.MOV?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ7V4MJWO3GNAM6WA%2F20180829%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20180829T082051Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=604800&amp;X-Amz-Signature=7ec66a41cc4c536ccc4abd42e5fea3621438563b114f72dd26f71c14eb4c4edd&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host" 
type="video/mp4" 
id="videoSrc">
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

I am getting just a blank space:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Why does not my video playing?

Comment: do you get any errors in the browsers console or network tabs (in Developer Tools)?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal, no. There are no errors or warnings in Chrome dev console.